# Difference between social network queries

Tags: sql, mysql, database

This is sourced from the Stanford Coursera self study DB class SQL quizzes:

> Students at your hometown high school have decided to organize their
>   social network using databases. So far, they have collected
>   information about sixteen students in four grades, 9-12. Here's the
>   schema:
>
> ```
> Highschooler (ID, name, grade)
> ```
>
> English: There is a high school student with unique ID and a given
>   first name in a certain grade.
>
> ```
> Friend (ID1, ID2)
> ```
>
> English: The student with ID1 is friends with the student with ID2.
>   Friendship is mutual, so if (123, 456) is in the Friend table, so is
>   (456, 123).
>
> ```
> Likes (ID1, ID2)
> ```
>
> English: The student with ID1 likes the student with ID2. Liking
>   someone is not necessarily mutual, so if (123, 456) is in the Likes
>   table, there is no guarantee that (456, 123) is also present.
>
> Database
>   [here](https://class.coursera.org/db/wiki/view?page=SocialData)
>
> **Prompt:** For each student A who likes a student B where the two are not friends, find if they have a friend C in common (who can introduce
>   them!). For all such trios, return the name and grade of A, B, and C.

I have a query which generates the correct results, and one which generates incorrect results, but I cannot logically figure out why the below query is incorrect. I have bolded the problem causing line, but am having trouble thinking through it and would appreciate a brief code review.

Working query due to the clause `and b.id not in (select id2 from friend where a.id=id1)`:

```
select distinct a.name, a.grade, b.name, b.grade, c.name, c.grade
from highschooler a, highschooler b, highschooler c, likes, friend
where a.id=likes.id1
and b.id=likes.id2
and a.id=friend.id1
-- this next line
and b.id not in (select id2 from friend where a.id=id1)
and b.id in (select id1 from friend where id2=c.id)
and a.id in (select id1 from friend where id2=c.id)
```

Incorrect query due to the clause `and b.id <>friend.id2`:

```
select distinct a.name, a.grade, b.name, b.grade, c.name, c.grade
from highschooler a, highschooler b, highschooler c, likes, friend
where a.id=likes.id1
and b.id=likes.id2
and a.id=friend.id1
-- as opposed to this one
and b.id <>friend.id2
and b.id in (select id1 from friend where id2=c.id)
and a.id in (select id1 from friend where id2=c.id)
```

Query 1 result:

Andrew  10  Cassandra   9   Gabriel 9

Austin  11  Jordan  12  Andrew  10

Austin  11  Jordan  12  Kyle    12

Query 2 result:

Andrew  10  Cassandra   9   Gabriel 9

Brittany    10  Kris    10  Haley   10

Austin  11  Jordan  12  Andrew  10

Austin  11  Jordan  12  Kyle    12

Gabriel 11  Alexis  11  Jessica 11

Comment: Please add source records for each table or setup a http://sqlfiddle.com I tried to find the database via the url, but I'm not going through an on-line course to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These 2 conditions have very different meanings:

> ```
> --1
> and b.id not in (select id2 from friend where a.id=id1)
> --2
> and b.id <> friend.id2
> ```

Let's say that `b.id` is `jack`, and `select id2 from friend where a.id=id1` is:

```
id2
---
alice
bob
```

In the first query, for the row of `jack` in the table `b`, you have effectively the condition "jack is not one of (alice, bob)". Which yields true, so the row will be included in the output.

In the second query, for the row of `jack` in the table `b`, you're effectively trying to join with the `friend` table where `id2` is not `jack`. In our example there are 2 such records, one with `alice` and one with `bob`. So in the output you will get 2 records for `jack`, one for `alice` and one for `bob`.

In the first query you either get the record with `jack` from `b` or not. In the second query you get `n` records for `jack`, where `n` is the number of records where `id2` is not `jack`. If all records are `jack` then you'll get no records from `b`. Completely different things.

Comment: your explanation makes sense (n records for jack vs 1 record), but i am still hazy on why Brittany would appear on one query but not the other. I added the results of both queries to my question for clarity.

Comment: because the record of Brittany satisfies the condition `b.id <> friend.id2`

Comment: but doesnt that say chris should not be friends with brittany (since brittany's id is not one of the ids (id2) of chris' friend)?

Comment: The `<>` operator (also known as `!=`) is not a "not one of" relationship. It means not equal. The expression is evaluated against every record in the `friend` table. For every record, you ask the database, "is id2 not equal to b.id?". If not equal, the record "matches". All the records match where id2 is not equal to `b.id`. If for example `b.id = 3` and in the `friend` table you have `id2` values `3, 4, 10`, then the query checks `3 <> 3 -> false`, `3 <> 4 -> true`, `3 <> 10 -> true`, so the records with 4 and 10 match.

Answer (score -1):

Your issues seem to come primarily from using ANSI-89 `join`s instead of using modern explicit `join`s. If you used modern `join`s it would be much easier to troubleshoot.

Your first version is making what is now known as an `inner join` while your second version is looking for a "not equal". That's why you get different results.